# Multiple order criteria in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models, Goal and Task. A goal has many tasks.

Goal has the field “priority” with a value from 1-5.

Task has the datetime field “due date.”

Right now, I have the list of tasks sorted by task.goal.priority. This works fine.

However I would like the sort order to actually be overdue tasks, followed by tasks due today, followed by tasks due tomorrow, followed by task.goal.priority.

I could run these queries separately and chain them together, but that doesn’t feel like the “Rails way.” How would you approach this?

Using Rails 4.0.4.

Thanks very much!

Comment: In that case, you should be able to just sort tasks by `due date desc`... `Task.joins(:goals).order("tasks.due_date desc, goals.priority asc")`.

Comment: Not quite. Any task that is due today or overdue, I want to show first. After that I do not want to sort by date, I want to sort by a different field. I think .partition() is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem with `.partition()`:

```
@tasks = @q.result.joins(:goal).order('goals.priority').partition(&:overdue)
```